# onCreateContextMenu is invoked with a null value for ContextMenuInfo

Tags: android, listview, android-cursor

I'm attempting to use a ContextMenu. I've successfully done this for a simple ListActivity using SimpleCursorAdapter.

Moving on I want to replace SimpleCursorAdapter with CursorAdapter but still retain the ContextMenu behaviour, so I've added the two mandatory override functions bindView and newView

```
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.check_row, parent, false);
    registerForContextMenu(view);
    return view;
}
```

Note the registerForContextMenu which replaces the registerForContextMenu(getListView()) in the onCreate method of the ListActivity. I found this necessary to get a call to onCreateContextMenu(...)

All this works (rows created with the expected widgets, callbacks on them working etc etc) except the ContextMenuInfo parameter supplied to onCreateContextMenu(...) is now null - stopping me from accessing the rowId.

Is there another trick to perform - perhaps in the bindView(...) method of the CursorAdapter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm answering the question - but I would point out that 'commonsware.com' provided the clues and direction, see above.

The problem

- Using CheckBox in the row layout impacts upon the use of Context menus
- CheckedTextView is, I believe, intended for multi-selection, it doesn't lend itself to initialization of the checked state.

The solution I adopted does the following

1. Use CheckedTextView
2. Extend from CursorAdapter to initialize the checked state during bindView(...)
   Note: This must manage displaying the correct icons too
3. Manage the CheckedTextView's state in onListItemClick(...) and record it in the dBase, not forgetting to update the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

That's not the right approach. You register the context menu for the `ListView`, not the rows. Call `registerForContextMenu()` up front, perhaps in `onCreate()` after you inflate the layout.

Comment: I want to put registerForContextMenu() in onCreate() but doing so results in the list entries not responding to long clicking - so there is no call to onCreateContextMenu() and thus no context menus.
Putting the register newView() results in a callback to onCreateContextMenu() - but now the ContextMenuInfo parameter is null.  
However - having the register in both newView() and onCreate() works insomuch as onCreateContextMenu() is called with a valid entry in ContextMenuInfo.
I don't believe this is 'right', there must be a better way?

Comment: "I want to put registerForContextMenu() in onCreate() but doing so results in the list entries not responding to long clicking - so there is no call to onCreateContextMenu() and thus no context menus." Check out http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Database/Constants/ for a sample of ListView and registerForContextMenu().

Comment: Thanks. I took this sample and attempted to recreate my issue here rather than in my own code - and aha!  
Modify row.xml to have a CheckBox and ContextMenus are no longer available. You don't need any logic to handle CheckBox, just add the following at the end of row.xml  

    <CheckBox 
        android:layout_below="@id/value" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/check" 
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/value"
        />

Comment: You could try using a CheckedTextView instead, which is the officially supported way of putting checkboxes in ListView rows. Give it the android:id of @android:id/text1 and Android should even handle it via CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE.

Comment: Good call - this is simpler and does allow context menu to work 'out of the box'. However it does present problems setting the initial checked state from a dB Cursor (which I've yet to resolve)